# Смысловое предложение в тексте

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> На момент подписания Сторонами настоящего Соглашения Поставщик осуществил свои обязательства в рамках договора в объеме и на сумму 000,000. Заказчик  ограничился предоставленным объемом услуг, согласно Приложения №1 к настоящему соглашению.

Вопрос: правильно ли написано в предложении "в объеме и на сумму..."?

Comment: Что такое "смысловое предложение"? В тексте всего два предложения, какое из них  является "смысловым"?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, если не указан объём, то пропущено: в полном.

Тогда всё на месте, иначе никак.

Ошибка стилистическая:

> ...согласно Приложения №1

Согласно чему - приложени**ю**.

Comment: Почему же стилистическая? Согласование падежей, то есть синтаксическая.

Comment: Потому что канцелярит.

Answer (score 1):

Не правильно. Союз "и" в этом предложении лишний. Правильно так:

*На момент подписания Сторонами настоящего Соглашения Поставщик осуществил свои обязательства в рамках договора **в объёме на сумму** 000,000. Заказчик ограничился предоставленным объемом услуг согласно Приложению №1 к настоящему соглашению.*

Правильно "согласно Приложению...", а перед "согласно" не нужна запятая.

Comment: "Объем на сумму х рублей" — что-то тут не так.

Comment: @М_Г Добавил две точки на ё, если Вы об этом.

Comment: Нет, не об этом. Наоборот, можно объесть на определенную сумму, но "объём на сумму" у меня в голове не укладывается. Возможно как-то так: "Выполнен объём работ на сумму х рублей", но не "обязательства в объёме на сумму х рублей" и не "договор в объёме на сумму х рублей"

Comment: @М_Г Мне глаз не режет. Я привык, что так пишут в контрактах, но не уверен, выходит ли это за рамки особенностей канцелярита. Ещё иногда пишут "в объёме (на сумму)". Не будем спорить, раз у нас нет надёжных аргументов. Вы можете предложить своё вариант ответа, только учтите, что это не обязательно объём **работ**.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы дать верный ответ, нужно знать, что хотел сказать автор. Можно было бы предположить "в полном объеме", но трудно поверить, что на момент подписания договора все уже выполнено в полном объеме. К тому же, "заказчик ограничился предоставленным объемом услуг", значит не все выполнено. Могу предложить два вариата

Вариант 1 (коль речь идет о "предоставленном объеме услуг")

На момент подписания Сторонами настоящего Соглашения Поставщик осуществил свои обязательства в рамках договора в объёме **услуг** на сумму 000,000 (**рублей**). Заказчик ограничился предоставленным объемом услуг согласно **Приложению** №1 к настоящему **Соглашению** (с прописной).

Вариант 2 (по grizzly)

На момент подписания Сторонами настоящего Соглашения Поставщик осуществил свои обязательства в рамках договора в **объёме (на сумму)** 000,000 (**рублей**). Заказчик ограничился предоставленным объемом услуг согласно **Приложению** №1 к настоящему **Соглашению** (с прописной).

Comment: Да, Вы всё учли. Хороший получился ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое предположение относительно известного одному только Поставщику смысла:

*На момент подписания Сторонами настоящего Соглашения Поставщик осуществил свои обязательства в рамках договора в полном объеме на сумму 0, 00 руб. Заказчик был ограничен в предоставлении ему объема услуг согласно Приложению №1 к настоящему соглашению.*

Comment: Долго думал, кто такой Поставщик смысла, но в конце концов догадался. Может, остальные участники сообразительней меня...

Comment: Можно выделить и другие пары слов с новыми законченными смыслами: "относительно известного", "предположение относительно". В этом и состоит работа Поставщика смысла :)